# How to create a view that returns all child records in a single row without aggregation?

Tags: postgresql, pivot, dynamic-sql, postgresql-15

I am an electrical engineer developing a parts library database and explorer tool for internal use in my organization. If anyone is familiar with OrCAD schematic capture tools, I am essentially recreating Cadence's CIS (Component Information System) backend and CIP (Component Information Portal) frontend , but I attempting to make them CAD software agnostic (should work with OrCAD, Altium, KiCAD, etc). I am nearly at the finish line, but am getting tripped up with the database views I need to feed data into my CAD software

At the moment I have 6 tables that all contain different types of data about each part:

| Table Name | Purpose | Relationships |
| --- | --- | --- |
| classes | Part categories | Parent to Main |
| main | Descriptive identifying information and data for CAD tools | Child of classes, Many-to-One. Parent to all other tables. Has Internal Part Number (IPN) used as foreign key in the other tables. |
| performance_spec | Part ratings used for automated part stress derating analysis. Part class determines criteria. | Child of main, One-to-One |
| manufacturing | Manufactures and Part Numbers | Child of main, Many-to-One |
| procurement | Suppliers and Part Numbers | Child of main, Many-to-One |
| compatibility | Cross reference alternative parts - Same Form, Fit, and Function with small differences in finish, reliability rating, etc. | Child of main, Many-to-One |

The main issue is that the CAD software, which communicates with the database via ODBC, cannot handle data split into multiple tables. So I need to create views (one per library -- grouped by class) that display queries of joined data from each of the tables.

The "Many-to-One" relationships between records is posing a particular problem because I need to represent all child records in the manufacturing table in a single row with the parent records in the main table.

I currently have a view that pulls in all of the child records using LEFT JOINs, but each child record in the manufacturing table creates a new row. I need some way to query the data so all of the child records are in a single row.

Here are simplified structures of the main and manufacturing tables along with some sample data.

**main**

| id | ipn | part_class | part_value | description | package | spec_doc | sch_symbol_kicad | pwb_fotprint_kicad | last_modified_user | last_modified_timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRT-00000001 | RES, Other | 10k | RES, SMT, Thick Film, 10k, 1%, 100ppm, 0.15 W | 0805 |  | res | resc0805 | FLast | 2023-05-04 07:38:53.782386-04 |
| 2 | PRT-00000002 | CAP, Tantalum, Solid | 15u | CAP, SMT, Tantalum, 220u, 10%, 10V, Reliability Grade D, Surge Test Option C | 2214 | MIL-PRF-55365/11 | cap_p | capc2214 | FLast | 2023-05-03 07:31:05.815801-04 |

**manufacturing**

| id | ipn | mfr | mpn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRT-00000001 | Yageo | RC0805JR-0710KL |
| 2 | PRT-00000001 | Stackpole Electronics Inc | RNCP0805FTD10K0 |
| 3 | PRT-00000001 | Susumu | RG2012P-103-B-T5 |
| 4 | PRT-00000002 | Kemet | T429F156K020DC4252 |
| 5 | PRT-00000002 | Kyocera AVX | CWR29JC156KDFC |

I'd like to create a view that looks like this:

| ipn | part_class | part_value | description | package | spec_doc | sch_symbol_kicad | pwb_fotprint_kicad | mfr_1 | mpn_1 | mfr_2 | mpn_2 | ... | mfr_n | mpn_n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

If someone could help me figure out a query to structure the manufacturing table with all records corresponding to the same IPN in a single row that would be a huge help. Joining that with the main table or any others should be straight-forward.

I have looked into pivoting and cross-tab functions, but every example I've seen has used aggregations on numerical data, which doesn't directly apply to me.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit-001**
Added SQL code to recreate tables:

```
CREATE TABLE components.main (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    ipn components.citext DEFAULT to_char(nextval('components.main_ipn_seq'::regclass), '"PRT-"fm00000000'::text) NOT NULL,
    part_class integer NOT NULL,
    part_value components.citext NOT NULL,
    description components.citext NOT NULL,
    spec_doc components.citext,
    sch_symbol_kicad components.citext,
    sch_symbol_altium components.citext,
    pwb_footprint_kicad components.citext,
    pwb_footprint_altium components.citext,
    step_file components.citext,
    lead_frm_reqd boolean DEFAULT false NOT NULL,
    lead_finish components.citext,
    datasheet components.citext,
    last_modified_user components.citext DEFAULT USER NOT NULL,
    last_modified_timestamp timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
    nrnd boolean DEFAULT false NOT NULL,
    bom_exclusion integer DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    pwb_exclusion integer DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    package components.citext
);

ALTER TABLE components.main ALTER COLUMN id ADD GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (
    SEQUENCE NAME components.main_id_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1
);

CREATE SEQUENCE components.main_ipn_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;

CREATE TABLE components.manufacturing (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    ipn components.citext NOT NULL,
    mfr components.citext NOT NULL,
    mpn components.citext NOT NULL,
    cage components.citext
);

ALTER TABLE components.manufacturing ALTER COLUMN id ADD GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (
    SEQUENCE NAME components.manufacturing_id_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1
);
```

**Edit-002**
I figured out how to get the view to display what I wanted using hierarchical queries, but it's pretty slow (~100-200ms for ~200 records). Any recommendations for performance optimization strategies would be greatly appreciated!

Here's my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW components.manf_pair_index
AS
SELECT manufacturing.id,
    manufacturing.ipn,
    manufacturing.mfr,
    manufacturing.mpn,
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY manufacturing.ipn ORDER BY manufacturing.id, manufacturing.ipn) AS pair_num
    FROM manufacturing;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW components.manf_flat
AS
SELECT manf_pair_index.ipn,
    max(manf_pair_index.mfr) FILTER (WHERE manf_pair_index.pair_num = 1) AS mfr_1,
    max(manf_pair_index.mpn) FILTER (WHERE manf_pair_index.pair_num = 1) AS mpn_1,
    max(manf_pair_index.mfr) FILTER (WHERE manf_pair_index.pair_num = 2) AS mfr_2,
    max(manf_pair_index.mpn) FILTER (WHERE manf_pair_index.pair_num = 2) AS mpn_2,
    max(manf_pair_index.mfr) FILTER (WHERE manf_pair_index.pair_num = 3) AS mfr_3,
    max(manf_pair_index.mpn) FILTER (WHERE manf_pair_index.pair_num = 3) AS mpn_3,
    max(manf_pair_index.mfr) FILTER (WHERE manf_pair_index.pair_num = 4) AS mfr_4,
    max(manf_pair_index.mpn) FILTER (WHERE manf_pair_index.pair_num = 4) AS mpn_4,
    max(manf_pair_index.mfr) FILTER (WHERE manf_pair_index.pair_num = 5) AS mfr_5,
    max(manf_pair_index.mpn) FILTER (WHERE manf_pair_index.pair_num = 5) AS mpn_5
    FROM manf_pair_index
    GROUP BY manf_pair_index.ipn;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW components.resistors
AS
SELECT main.ipn,
    main.nrnd,
    main.part_class,
    main.part_value,
    main.description,
    main.package,
    main.spec_doc,
    main.lead_finish,
    main.lead_frm_reqd,
    manf_flat.mfr_1,
    manf_flat.mpn_1,
    manf_flat.mfr_2,
    manf_flat.mpn_2,
    manf_flat.mfr_3,
    manf_flat.mpn_3,
    manf_flat.mfr_4,
    manf_flat.mpn_4,
    manf_flat.mfr_5,
    manf_flat.mpn_5,
    compatibility.comperable_ipn,
    main.sch_symbol_kicad,
    main.sch_symbol_altium,
    main.pwb_footprint_kicad,
    main.pwb_footprint_altium,
    main.step_file,
    main.bom_exclusion,
    main.pwb_exclusion
    FROM main
        LEFT JOIN manf_flat ON main.ipn::text = manf_flat.ipn::text
        LEFT JOIN compatibility ON main.ipn::text = compatibility.ipn::text
    WHERE main.part_class > 28 AND main.part_class < 45
    ORDER BY main.ipn;
```